# Counting specific lines that don't contain specific word

Tags: grep, bioinformatics, biopython

Please I have question: I have a file like this

```
@HWI-ST273:296:C0EFRACXX:2:2101:17125:145325/1
TTAATACACCCAACCAGAAGTTAGCTCCTTCACTTTCAGCTAAATAAAAG
+
8?8A;DDDD;@?++8A?;C;F92+2A@19:1*1?DDDECDE?B4:BDEEI
@BBBB-ST273:296:C0EFRACXX:2:1303:5281:183410/1
TAGCTCCTTCGCTTTCAGCTAAATAAAAGCCCAGTACTTCTTTTTTACCA
+
CCBFFFFFFHHHHJJJJJJJJJIIJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJIJJJJJI
@HWI-ST273:296:C0EFRACXX:2:1103:16617:140195/1
AAGTTAGCTCCTTCGCTTTCAGCTAAATAAAAGCCCAGTACTTCTTTTTT
+
@C@FF?EDGFDHH@HGHIIGEGIIIIIEDIIGIIIGHHHIIIIIIIIIII
@HWI-ST273:296:C0EFRACXX:2:1207:14316:145263/1
AATACACCCAACCAGAAGTTAGCTCCTTCGCTTTCAGCTAAATAAAAGCC
+
CCCFFFFFHHHHHJJJJJJJIJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJIJ
```

I

I'm interested just about the line that starts with '@HWI', but I want to count all the lines that are not starting with '@HWI'. In the example shown, the result  will be 1 because there's one line that starts with '@BBB'.

To be more clear: I just want to know know the number of the first line of the patterns (that are 4 line that repeated) that are not '@HWI'; I hope I'm clear enough. Please tell me if you need more clarification

Comment: Please, use the code formatting for the data, not blockquote, so we can see where the lines start and end.

Comment: Yes i  made mistake , it's fine now

Comment: There is no line that starts with `@BBB`. Do you mean to say "Of all the lines that start with `@`, I want to count how many do not start with `@HWI`?" That's what I think you mean, but if so please update your question with that. And kindly show your attempts.

Comment: very sorry , i forgot to  update the exemple

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed, you can use its extended address to print every fourth line, then use grep to count the ones that don't start with @HWI:

```
sed -n '1~4p' file.fastq | grep -cv '^@HWI'
```

Otherwise, you can use e.g. Perl

```
perl -ne 'print if 1 == $. % 4' -- file.fastq | grep -cv '^@HWI'
```

`$.` contains the current line number, `%` is the modulo operator.

But once we're running Perl, we don't need grep anymore:

```
perl -lne '++$c if 1 == $. % 4; END { print $c }' -- file.fastq
```

`-l` removes newlines from input and adds them to output.